# How to change value in a BTreeMap container

Tags: reference, rust

Code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Haha {
    data: i32,
}

use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: BTreeMap<i8, Option<Box<Haha>>> = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert(1, Some(Box::new(Haha { data: 3 })));
    map.insert(2, None);

    for (key, value) in map.iter_mut() {
        if value.is_none() {        // if find `None`, change it to a `Some(Haha)`
            value = Some(Box::new(Haha { data: 5 }));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a function that when I get the value `None` in `BTreeMap.value`, I change it to `Some` value, not a reference. But it comes out a mistake:

```
 error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> Untitled.rs:15:12
   |
15 |            value = Some(Box::new(Haha{data: 5}));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected mutable reference, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<Haha>>`
              found type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<Haha>>`
   = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
           - .unwrap()
```

Because using `map.iter_mut()` I can only get the reference. How to send the true value `Some(Haha)` but not a reference to the mut reference `value`? If I change to `value = & mut Some(Box::new(Haha { data: 5 }));` Because `Some(Box...)` will be destructed, so it will come out another mistake.

Comment: Another note on style: rather omit the explicit type annotation for your hashmap. The compiler is usually perfectly able to figure out the type ;-) Also: instead of using `iter_mut()` (and `iter()`) in a for loop directly, usually we write `for ... in &mut map { ... }`. :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! The second is useful. But at first I wrote `let mut map: BTreeMap = BTreeMap::new();`, but it turned out an error: `error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 0`. So I changed to write the type name... Could you tell me the right way to use it?

Comment: Just write `let mut map = BTreeMap::new()` ;-)

Comment: Got it~ Thank you for your patience with a novice like me~ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `value` is a mutable reference (due to `iter_mut()`), just dereference it:

```
*value = Some(Box::new(Haha{data: 5}));
```

And it will work nicely.